# code refactoring a java script compiler

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, global, local

I was trying to understand a JavaScript package compiler and redesigned the basic structure.
Every time a string is compiled it is added to the `SrcTable` array. and thrown at the output.
however, to get the output the `SrcTable` has to be declared global. [but the example from which i am building this code has that variable declared as local](https://github.com/gameclosure/js.io/blob/master/packages/preprocessors/compiler.js#L6).
I would like to understand:-
1.Why can i not declare the variable as local in here?
2. What do i need to change to make it work as local?

the `srcTable` is in the `preprocessors.compiler` variable.

```js
function resolveRequest(request) {
  var match = request.match(/^\s*import\s+(.*)$/),
    imports = {};

  if (match) {
    match[1].replace(/\s*([\w.\-$]+)(?:\s+as\s+([\w.\-$]+))?,?/g, function(_, from, as) {
      imports = {
        from: from,
        as: as || from
      };
    });
  }
  return imports;
}

var preprocessors = {
  import: "var importExpr = /^(\\s*)(import\\s+[^=+*\"'\\r\\n;\\/]+|from\\s+[^=+\"'\\r\\n;\\/ ]+\\s+import\\s+[^=+\"'\\r\\n;\\/]+)(;|\\/|$)/gm;" +
    "function replace(raw, p1, p2, p3) {" +
    "  return p1 + 'jsio(\"' + p2 + '\")' + p3;" +
    "};" +
    "exports = function(src) {" +
    "  return src.replace(importExpr, replace);" +
    "};",
  compiler: "srcTable = [];" + // this array needs to be local
    "        exports = function (src) {" +
    "          var jsioNormal = " + /^(.*)jsio\s*\(\s*(['"].+?['"])\s*(,\s*\{[^}]+\})?\)/gm + "\n;" +
    "          var match = jsioNormal.exec(src);\n" +
    "          if(match) {" +
    "            var request = eval(match[2]);\n" +
    "            jsio(request, ['import', 'compiler']);\n" +
    "          } \n" +
    "          srcTable.push(src);"+
    "          return '';\n" +
    "        };" +
    "        exports.compile = function(request) {" +
    "          jsio(request, ['import', 'compiler']);" +
    "        };" + 
    "        exports.generateSrc = function (callback) {"+
    "          callback(srcTable);"+
    "        };"
};

function _require(previousCtx, request, p) {
  var p = p || ['import'];
  var request = resolveRequest(request);
  var src = eval(request.from);

  p.forEach(function(name, index) {
    var args = name == 'import' ? [] : null;
    var preprocessor = jsio('import preprocessors.' + name, args);

    src = preprocessor(src);
  });

  var code = "(function (__) { with (__) {" + src + "}});";
  var fn = eval(code);
  var context = makeContext();
  fn(context);
  previousCtx[request.as] = context.exports;
  return context.exports;
}

function makeContext() {
  return {
    jsio: function(request, p) {
      return _require(this, request, p);
    },
    exports: {}
  };
}

var jsio = makeContext().jsio;

var example = {
  app: "import example.calculator as calculator;" +
    "   calculator.add(2, 3);",

  calculator: "import example.print as print;" +
    "          exports = {" +
    "            add: function (a, b) {" +
    "              print(a+b);" +
    "            }" +
    "          }",

  print: "exports = function(res) {" +
    "       console.log(res);" +
    "     }"
};

var compiler = jsio('import preprocessors.compiler;');
compiler.compile('import example.app;');
compiler.generateSrc(function(src) {
  console.log(src);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the code is being compiled with the java-script `with` context, so, the function that is evaluating the code, needs to be cached, otherwise compiling the same code every time, will recreate the instance. 
so the solution is

```js
function resolveRequest(request) {
  var match = request.match(/^\s*import\s+(.*)$/),
    imports = {};

  if (match) {
    match[1].replace(/\s*([\w.\-$]+)(?:\s+as\s+([\w.\-$]+))?,?/g, function(_, from, as) {
      imports = {
        from: from,
        as: as || from
      };
    });
  }
  return imports;
}

var preprocessors = {
  import: "var importExpr = /^(\\s*)(import\\s+[^=+*\"'\\r\\n;\\/]+|from\\s+[^=+\"'\\r\\n;\\/ ]+\\s+import\\s+[^=+\"'\\r\\n;\\/]+)(;|\\/|$)/gm;" +
    "function replace(raw, p1, p2, p3) {" +
    "  return p1 + 'jsio(\"' + p2 + '\")' + p3;" +
    "};" +
    "exports = function(src) {" +
    "  return src.replace(importExpr, replace);" +
    "};",
  compiler: "var srcTable = [];\n" +
    "        exports = function (src) {\n" +
    "          var jsioNormal = " + /^(.*)jsio\s*\(\s*(['"].+?['"])\s*(,\s*\{[^}]+\})?\)/gm + "\n;" +
    "          var match = jsioNormal.exec(src);\n" +
    "          if(match) {\n" +
    "            var request = eval(match[2]);\n" +
    "            jsio(request, ['import', 'compiler']);\n" +
    "          } \n" +
    "          srcTable.push(src);\n" +
    "          return '';\n" +
    "        };\n" +
    "        exports.compile = function(request) {\n" +
    "          jsio(request, ['import', 'compiler']);\n" +
    "        };\n" +
    "        exports.generateSrc = function (callback) {\n" +
    "          callback(srcTable);\n" +
    "        };\n"
};

var _cache_context = [];

function _require(previousCtx, request, p) {
  var p = p || ['import'];
  var request = resolveRequest(request);
  var src = loadModule(request).src;

  p.forEach(function(name, index) {
    var args = name == 'import' ? [] : null;
    var preprocessor = jsio('import preprocessors.' + name, args);
    src = preprocessor(src);
  });

  if (src) {
    if (!_cache_context[request.from]) {
      var code = "(function (__) { with (__) {\n" + src + "\n}});";
      var fn = eval(code);
      var context = makeContext();
      fn(context);
      _cache_context[request.from] = context.exports;
    }
    previousCtx[request.as] = _cache_context[request.from];
    return previousCtx[request.as];
  }
}

function loadModule(request){
 var src = eval(request.from);

 return {
   src: src,
   path: request.from
 } 
}

function makeContext() {
  return {
    jsio: function(request, p) {
      return _require(this, request, p);
    },
    exports: {}
  };
}

var jsio = makeContext().jsio;

var example = {
  app: "import example.calculator as calculator;" +
    "   calculator.add(2, 3);",

  calculator: "import example.print as print;" +
    "          exports = {" +
    "            add: function (a, b) {" +
    "              print(a+b);" +
    "            }" +
    "          }",

  print: "exports = function(res) {" +
    "       console.log(res);" +
    "     }"
};

var compiler = jsio('import preprocessors.compiler;');
compiler.compile('import example.app;');
compiler.generateSrc(function(src) {
  console.log(src);
});
```